# Fetch Local phonebook contacts From SIM card only android

Tags: android, contacts, local, sim-card

I want to know if its possible to fetch contacts which exist in SIM card or phonebook only. Right now I am using the following code to fetch contacts and it fetches all the contacts even my gmail and Facebook Contacts.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
            {
                while (cursor.moveToNext())
                {

                    PhoneBookUserEntity user = new PhoneBookUserEntity();
                    // Pick out the ID, and the Display name of the
                    // contact from the current row of the cursor
                    user.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID)));
                    user.setPhoneBookName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                    if(user.getphonebookname().length() > 4)
                    username = user.getphonebookname();//.substring(0,4);
                    else
                        username = user.getphonebookname();//.substring(0,1);
                    String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
                    //    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ user.getId(), null, null); 
                    while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
                        user.sePhoneNumber(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));                 
                    } 
                    phones.close(); 
                    //}
                    // user.sePhoneNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))); 

                    Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + user.getId(), null, null); 
                    while (emails.moveToNext()) { 
                        // This would allow you get several email addresses 
                        user.setEmailAddress(emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA))); 
                    } 
                    emails.close(); 
                    user.setImageURI(getPhotoUri(user.getId()));
                    SearchContactsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            _progressDialog.setMessage("Copying over your local phone book. Retrieving contact information for \n"+ username.toUpperCase());
                        }
                    });
                    arraylist.add(user);
                }

            }
            cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 6):

For Sim contact only you can use below code

```
private void allSIMContact()
    {
        try
        {
            String ClsSimPhonename = null; 
            String ClsSimphoneNo = null;

            Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn"); 
            Cursor cursorSim = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri,null,null,null,null);

            Log.i("PhoneContact", "total: "+cursorSim.getCount());

            while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) 
            {      
                ClsSimPhonename =cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name"));
                ClsSimphoneNo = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number"));
                ClsSimphoneNo.replaceAll("\\D","");
                ClsSimphoneNo.replaceAll("&", "");
                ClsSimPhonename=ClsSimPhonename.replace("|","");

                Log.i("PhoneContact", "name: "+ClsSimPhonename+" phone: "+ClsSimphoneNo);
            }        
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = getContacts();
    getBundleValues2();

    String displayName = "";
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        //taking id name and phone number from contacts using content provider
        String displayid = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String displayphnno = "";

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

            Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = ?", new String[] { displayid }, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                displayphnno = pCur
                        .getString(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                        + "\n";

                ContactProviderViewGroup v6;
                //using view group appending it to an activity
                if (colorFlag) {
                    v6 = new ContactProviderViewGroup(this, displayName,
                            displayphnno, passedid, colorFlag);
                    colorFlag = false;
                } else {
                    v6 = new ContactProviderViewGroup(this, displayName,
                            displayphnno, passedid, colorFlag);
                    colorFlag=true;
                }
                LL1.addView(v6);
            }
            pCur.close();
        }

    }

}

private void getBundleValues2() {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle myBundle = i.getExtras();

    if (myBundle != null) {
        passedid = myBundle.getInt("gid");
    }
}

private Cursor getContacts() {
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER };

    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
            + ("1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
            sortOrder);
}
```