# Read SIM card contacts

Tags: android, sdk, sim-card

I am developping an android application, and i want to read or get the  Sim card contacts  by a button click.
Could you help me ?

my button xml code is :

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/third"
     android:layout_below="@+id/third"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:text="Read contact" 
     android:onClick="contactsAccess"/>
```

I need the java code to be used inside the methode (contactsAccess).

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412634/fetch-local-phonebook-contacts-from-sim-card-only-android/10412757#10412757)

Comment: thank you for your answer but i need just the sim card contacts , not contacts saved on the phone

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {


    Button sim_btn;


    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_VIEW);

    sim_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sim_btn.setOnClickListener(this); 
     getallsimnumber();
       }


getallsimnumber(){
 try
        {
            String ClsSimPhonename = null; 
            String ClsSimphoneNo = null;

            Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn"); 
            Cursor cursorSim = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri,null,null,null,null);

            Log.i("PhoneContact", "total: "+cursorSim.getCount());

            while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) 
            {      
                ClsSimPhonename =cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name"));
                ClsSimphoneNo = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number"));
                ClsSimphoneNo.replaceAll("\\D","");
                ClsSimphoneNo.replaceAll("&", "");
                ClsSimPhonename=ClsSimPhonename.replace("|","");

                Log.i("PhoneContact", "name: "+ClsSimPhonename+" phone: "+ClsSimphoneNo);
            }        
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```